# Can AWS Glue call Step functions for data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, aws-glue, aws-step-functions

I have a requirement where AWS Glue needs to call/invoke Step functions for data required during ETL process. Here is the entire process:

1. Glue reads csv from S3
2. Glue invokes Step functions for each record in csv file
3. Step function has 2 steps/state/task and calls 2 different api (developed in .net core/deployed in aws eks) for data.
   Output of 1st step is input for 2nd step.
4. Output from Step function will be used by Glue for transformation.

So got 2 problems to solve, invoking step from glue and step functions calling apis.
Please suggest.

Comment: You are asking about a very broad task, not even a question, that should be split into multiple, more specific questions. And once you have it broken down into smaller pieces (like you already have done at some degree - how do I call step-function from glue job?) then it would become easier for you to solve it via trying different approaches and looking up for the solutions on internet docs yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Its a very broad question. But the simple answer is, you can interact with step functions using the boto3 library that comes in the glue environment. You would also be able to extract the status of the step function once its been kicked off and additionaly also get the output values from the function invocation.